# Count spesific number in a string of number in excel

Tags: excel, count, numbers, countif

I have an ID with the format is : xxxxxxxx ( 8 numbers).
Example : 16515134

3 first numbers is faculty code (In the example : 165)
2 numbers after that is year you enter the university (In the example : 15)
3 last numbers is personal number (In the example : 134)

I have about 100 hundred IDs in 100 rows in one cell.

I want to count the specific 4th and 5th number position (year you enter the university).

Example :

16515134

16515145

13216124

I want to count the "15" (the 4th dan 5th number). So it will give 2 as the answer.

So how to do that ? I'm already tried use =COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"***15*") but it only works when it is a text not a number.

Comment: While posting your question in the "Title" field you were asked "What is your programming question?". So what is your *programming* question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A20,4,2)="15"))
```

[image]

Comment: beat you to it, this time. :)

Comment: but i am want know what does the "--" (without "")  mean?

Comment: @ShalahuddinAl-Ayyubbi the material inside the **()** is an array of **TRUE** / **FALSE**  ..............the double **-** changes that to an array of  **0/1**